# What is the source of ValueError in pycaret and how to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, model, pycaret

I have a dataframe comprised of 11 columns one of which, Weekday, is categorical.

```
columns = ['Series' 'Year' 'Month' 'Day' 'Weekday' 'Number1' 'Number2' 'Number3'
 'Number4' 'Number5' 'Number6']
```

Since data originally was given as a timeseries dataframe, I am using the following approach ([Time Series Forecasting Tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/tutorial-time-series-forecasting)) to forecast the values of six of the numerical columns utilizing `pycaret` python package.

However, during model determination and comparison defined in the following function:

```
def ml_modelling(train, test) -> None:
    """This function models the given timeseries dataset

    Args:
        train (pd.DataFrame): _description_
        test (pd.DataFrame): _description_
    """
    # Now that we have done the train-test-split, we are ready to train a
    # machine learning model on the train data, score it on the test data and
    # evaluate the performance of our model. In this example, I will use
    # PyCaret; an open-source, low-code machine learning library in Python that
    # automates machine learning workflows.
    numerical_columns = list(train.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.values)
    targets = [col for col in numerical_columns if col.startswith('Number')]
    for target_var in targets:

        s = setup(data=train,
                  test_data=test,
                  target=target_var,
                  fold_strategy='timeseries',
                  numeric_features=numerical_columns,
                  fold=5,
                  transform_target=True,
                  session_id=123)

        models()

        # Now to train machine learning models, you just need to run one line
        best = compare_models(sort='MAE')
        print(f'Output from compare_models for column {target_var}: \n', best)
        print('##############################################################')
```

I am receiving the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/username/OneDrive/Desktop/project/main_script.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/username/OneDrive/Desktop/project/main_script.py", line 56, in main
    ml_modelling(train, test)
  File "c:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\project\utilities.py", line 1076, in ml_modelling
    s = setup(data=train,
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycaret\regression.py", line 571, in setup
    return pycaret.internal.tabular.setup(
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycaret\internal\tabular.py", line 607, in setup        
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Column type forced is either target column or doesn't exist in the dataset.
```

I would appreciate if you let me know what mistakes I am making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to make the following change inside `setup` function:

```
numeric_features=numerical_columns
```

to

```
numeric_features=[col for col in numerical_columns if col != target_var]
```

since, in any given iteration over target variables, the target cannot be considered a `numeric_features` anymore.